# Python - How to automaticly open first available serial port (COM/tty)

Tags: python, serial, python-3, uart

I am new at Python and I want to learn serial communication between Raspberry and other devices like PC, arduino, sensors...
I often plug and unplug devices like arduino, FTDI, etc. to COM port... I want to program simple serial terminal to learn how to communicate via UART with MCU and sensors. But, i want to make automaticly recognize available serial port (COM or tty)... Because every time when i plug other device instead of first i have to manualy retype serial.port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi this is how to solve this problem:

```
import serial.tools.list_ports
ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
print(ports[0][0])
```